# jQuery prepend problem - SVG doesn't work

Tags: jquery

i have a code

```
$( "a" ).prepend("<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 152.9 43.4" style="enable-background:new 0 0 152.9 43.4;" xml:space="preserve"><path d="M151.9,13.6c0,0,3.3-9.5-85-8.3c-97,1.3-58.3,29-58.3,29s9.7,8.1,69.7,8.1c68.3,0,69.3-23.1,69.3-23.1 s1.7-10.5-14.7-18.4" /></svg>");
```

and it's doesn't work :/ every other HTML works fine, but not this SVG. unfortunately I need to add it this way. Any idea why this doesn't work?

Comment: You have a quotes mismatch. Wrap the `<svg>` html in single quotes instead of doubles or escape all of it's attributes double quotes

Comment: @charlietfl xD stupid me. Thanks a lot :D